# PopupWindow background disappears. It becomes transparent automatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am showing a PopupWindow and setting its background as 9 patch image. PopupWindows background becomes transparent when it becomes visible. I am unable to find out issue. How should it be resolved?

Here is my code.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

 View panel = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_collection, null);

 panel.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams
         (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 panel.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

 int status_bar_height = 0;
 int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height" ,
         "dimen" , "android");
 if(resourceId > 0){
     status_bar_height = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
 }

 popupWindow = new PopupWindow(panel,
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

 Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.menu_popup_bg);

 popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     popupWindow.setElevation(48);
 }
 popupWindow.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
 popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
 popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
 popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

 popupWindow.showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.END, 0,
         status_bar_height);
```

Here is my add_collection.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_6sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:text="Add New Collection"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp" />

    <com.suntec.oneread.customviews.OREditText
        android:id="@+id/et_collection_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="Collection Name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords|textCapSentences"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/_160sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textColorHint="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSave"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:background="@color/btn_background"
                android:text="Save"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:background="@color/btn_background"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is menu_popup_bg.xml file. I am setting drawable as 9 patch image.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/menu_bg_light_grey" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_bg_light_grey" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/menu_bg_light_grey" />
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_bg_light_grey" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Can you share menu_popup_bg  and add_collection file layout?

Comment: I have edited my question you can find layout and drawable files there

Comment: I think you have default state missing in selector .. write `<item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_bg_light_grey" />` as last line ..

Comment: I have directly set 9 patch to background of Popupwindow without selectors but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tested and it's work, can you test with another image (menu_bg_light_grey)